# saving files with cordova plugin file in ios

Tags: ios, image, file, cordova

I've developer ad an app where the users can select images from their gallery and save in a business card.
So the process is this:
1) Select the image
2) The app copy the image into a folder.
3) After the copy , I save the path into my database.
The problem is that the image is deleted after few seconds.
I've tried with cordova.file.dataDirectory, cordova.file.documentsDirectory, cordova.data.syncedDataDirectory ...and nothing. The image is being deleted after 2/3 boots of the app.
Someone knows why?

This is the [link](http://www.informatica-milano.com/code.js) to the code.

Comment: It would help to see the code you're using to copy the image to a folder, as well as the folder path you're copying to.

Comment: Ok, i've edited my questione with the code. Thank you!

Comment: Can you reduce that to the smallest example that still exhibits the problem? Otherwise, it's difficult to pin things down.

That said, it _looks_ like you're reading the file and the writing it back out. Why not use the copy/move functionality provided by the API? See specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-file-system-api-20110419/#methods-2